# Unable to remove marker cluster group completely from the map in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, leaflet-plugins

I am having a weird issue with removing a `MarkerClusterGroup` layer from the map. When at a zoom level more than 5, I want to show markers on the map in a MarkerClusterGroup layer. When zoomed to less than level 5, I want to remove the markers.

Given the code below, most of the markers remove, but a small cluster of markers in the center of the map stubbornly remains (all the markers and clusters are in the same FeatureGroup).

```js
const LAYERS = {};
const BOUNDS = null;

const makeFoo = async (bounds) => {
    // get points for `bounds` from the server
    const url = `server/?bounds`;
    const response = await fetch(url);

    if (response.ok) {
        LAYERS.foo = L.markerClusterGroup();
        const records = await response.json();
        records.forEach((r) => LAYERS.foo.addLayer(L.marker(new L.LatLng(r.lat, r.lng)));
        map.addLayer(LAYERS.foo);
    }
}

const map = L.map( 'map', {});
map.on('moveend', function(e) {    
    if (map.getZoom() > 5) {
        if (BOUNDS) {
            if (map.bounds.contains(BOUNDS)) {
                if (!map.hasLayer(LAYERS.foo)) makeFoo(map.getBounds());
            }
            else {
                BOUNDS = map.getBounds();
                makeFoo(BOUNDS);
            }
        }
        else {
            BOUNDS = map.getBounds();
            makeFoo(BOUNDS);
        }
    }
    else if (zoom <= 5) {
        if (map.hasLayer(LAYERS.foo)) map.removeLayer(LAYERS.foo);
    }
});
```

When I type the following in the browser console, no layer is found, but I can see the points.

```js
>> map.hasLayer(LAYERS.foo)
← false
```

What is going on? How can I get rid of these ghost marker clusters?

Comment: Please edit your question and explain a bit more about the logic of your code, don't let people guess what you are trying to do.

Comment: well, I thought it was pretty clear from the code, but I've added another sentence describing what I am trying to do. I hope it is clearer now. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without actually testing I would say that what's missing is removing possible existing marker cluster layer when creating a new one.

So probably the code should be something like:

```
const makeFoo = async (bounds) => {
    // get points for `bounds` from the server
    const url = `server/?bounds`;
    const response = await fetch(url);

    if (response.ok) {
        if (LAYERS.foo && map.hasLayer(LAYERS.foo)) {
          map.removeLayer(LAYERS.foo);
        }
        LAYERS.foo = L.markerClusterGroup();
        const records = await response.json();
        records.forEach((r) => LAYERS.foo.addLayer(L.marker(new L.LatLng(r.lat, r.lng)));
        map.addLayer(LAYERS.foo);
    }
}
```

Comment: You set me on the right path… instead of checking for and adding to the existing markercluster layer, I was creating new layers but not assigning them to anything. That is why I was not able to remove them. Thanks